# Circular Distributed Hash Table overlay P2P network

Tags: p2p, dht, churn

I think I'm missing something here or confusing terms perhaps.

What happens to the key:value pairs stored at a peer in the overlay DHT when that peer leaves the p2p network? Are they moved to the new appropriate nearest successor? Is there a standard mechanism for this if that is the case.

My understand is that the successors and predecessor peer information of adjacent peers has to be modified as expected when a peer leaves however I can't seem to find information on what happens to the actual data stored at that peer. How is the data kept complete in the DHT as peer churn occurs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually is not part of the abstract routing algorithm that's at the core of a DHT but implementation-specific behavior instead.

Usually you will want to store the data on multiple nodes neighboring the target key that way you'll get some redundancy to handle the failures.

To keep it alive you can either have the originating node republish it in regular intervals or have the storage nodes replicate it among each other. The latter causes a bit less traffic if done properly, but is more complicated to implement.